# How to install an external package to /usr/local without troubling Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install a package called Geant4 by compiling from source (HomeBrew actually has the package but it's an old version and doesn't have support for Python which I need).

I want to put the Geant4 package in /usr/local/geant4 (perhaps this is not the proper place to put it in OSX?).

Now, the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#can-i-install-my-own-stuff-to-usrlocal) has some instructions on how to install external stuff, but when I do `brew diy`, I get the error message:

> Error: Couldn't determine build system

The command I should use to configure Geant4 is:

```
cd ~/my-build-directory
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/geant4 ~/Downloads/geant4.10.01.p01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew diy` makes a good effort to determine how to build a package, but it doesn't always get it right. In the case of custom packages, it's probably best to install them into `$(brew --prefix)/Cellar/$package/$version`, just as Homerew would -- that way, you can interact with the package using `brew link`, etc. You *can* also install it to `/usr/local` or anywhere you like, but mimicking Homebrew works really well.

In your case, you could probably install it with something like:

```
cd /my-build-directory
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)/Cellar/geant4/10.01.p01 ~/Downloads/geant4.10.01.p01
brew link geant4
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was searching for.